# mochaJS: iterating in json

Tags: javascript, json, api, mocha.js, chai

i have following issue, i have part of json returned by api:

```html
...
"name": "NEWS",
"products": {
  "10432471": {
     "id": 10432471,
     "productConfig": [
      ...
     ]
  },
  "10432481": {
     "id": 10432481
  },
  "17300241": {
     "id": 17300241
  },
  "17300251": {
     "id": 17300251,
     "productConfig": [
      ...
     ]
  },
  "18420501": {
     "id": 18420501
  }
}
...
```

and i want to get random simple product id (simple product means that it dont have productConfig field inside)

```html
        for (i=0;i<res.body.menu.categories.length;i++){
          if(res.body.menu.categories[i].name=='NEWS'){ 
              availableProducts = Object.keys(res.body.menu.categories[i].products);
              console.log ('avbl prods from news category: ',availableProducts);
              for (j=0;;j++){      
                random=Math.floor(Math.random()*Object.keys(res.body.menu.categories[i].products).length);       
                if(assert.notInclude(res.body.menu.categories[i].products[random],'productConfig')){
                  availableProductIdForDelivery = res.body.menu.categories[i].products[random].id;
                  break;
                }
              }
          }
        }
```

This code gives me error in line with second if (if(assert.notInclude....))      Uncaught AssertionError: object tested must be an array, a map, an object, a set, a string, or a weakset, but undefined given.

So, inside "products" we dont have array, becouse there're {}, not []?
There's any other way to iterate beetween products (their numerical names are changed everyday) and save id to availableProductIdForDelivery

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation: http://www.chaijs.com/api/assert/#method_notinclude

You see that the first parameter must be Array, String or haystack. Let's take a look at the error message you have given:

> Uncaught AssertionError: object tested must be an array, a map, an
>   object, a set, a string, or a weakset, but undefined given.

This error message indicates that something was `undefined` instead of the possible expected types listed in the message. I guess it was the first parameter, but it might be the third as well, since you did not pass anything as the third parameter, so it is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

> So, inside "products" we dont have array, becouse there're {}, not []?

Correct. As far as I can tell, you are trying to apply an assertion to `res.body.menu.categories[i].products[random]`, but because `products` is an object (and not a list) attempting to retrieve an index (as oppose to one of the keys defined in the object) with `products[random]` returns `undefined`.

If you want to create a list of products in order to evaluate their contents, you may be able to use `Object.values(res.body.menu.categories[i].products)[random]`. As far as I am aware, this feature is only standard as of ES2017. You may also be able to apply a map function to your `availableProducts` object to retrieve the corresponding values for each product key.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for help, now its works as i want. Below my solution, maybe it help someone in the future:

```html
        for (i=0;i<res.body.menu.categories.length;i++){
          if(res.body.menu.categories[i].name=='NEWS'){  //random simple product from 'news' category
              availableProducts = Object.keys(res.body.menu.categories[i].products);
              console.log ('avbl prods from news category: ',availableProducts);
              while(availableProductIdForDelivery==''){      
                random=Math.floor(Math.random()*Object.keys(res.body.menu.categories[i].products).length);       
                  if((Object.values(res.body.menu.categories[i].products)[random].productConfig).length==0)
                    availableProductIdForDelivery = Object.values(res.body.menu.categories[i].products)[random].id;                
              }
              console.log('random simple product: '+availableProductIdForDelivery) ;
          }
        }
```